# "Refused to set unsafe header 'Cookie' " while sending cookies with GET request in angular 6

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cookies, spring-security

I am using spring security with angular 6. When i login using basic Auth  server sends  a cookie **JessionID** with response. I want to send this cookie with other request for authentication purpose but it gives me error `Refused to set unsafe header 'Cookie'` . When i hit the same endpoint from postman with same cookie in header it works.

**Below is the method in angular:**

**Note**: Currently i am manually adding it with headers.

```
private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/hi';
     header = new HttpHeaders().set("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=A2A75EC9A3E1172D60060C6E708549B5");
    getMessage() :Observable<Message>{
      return this.http.get<Message>(this.heroesUrl,{headers:this.header});
    }
```

**Response which i get when i login using basic Auth**

[image: Response which i get when i login using basic Auth]

Comment: I had the same problem but in a different scenario. You cannot set Cookie header manually with the request in your code. Also if the cookie is httponly, then it cannot be accessed by the code. However when I used postman to make a request, it worked. In my case, I evaded this issue by making my app on the same port as the server. The cookie gets sent automatically if the request comes from same origin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**You can't do this**, cause the browser doesn't allow you to do it. Let me describe the problem here:

Did you notice the `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=......; Path=/; HttpOnly` in your response headers? Well, The problem is the **HttpOnly** flag. Actually :) it's not a problem, it's a feature to prevent attacks that aim to steal your browser cookies:

> **HttpOnly** is a flag added to cookies that tell the browser not to display the cookie through client-side scripts (document.cookie and others). ... When you set a cookie with the HttpOnly flag, it informs the browser that this special cookie should only be accessed by the server

So the browser doesn't allow any javascript code to access this variable. If you could change that value, then it's not a `HttpOnly` flagged cookie anymore:)

If you want to send this cookie via javascript, you should send it via the `Authorization` header for example and write middleware in Java server so that it captures these values from the `Authorization` header and think of them as JSESSIONID cookie. No more options for you :)

Comment: as you mentioned javascript doesn't have access to the cookies how i am gonna use it to send with authorization header?

Comment: Why you want to send it, Browser should send it automatically via Cookie header. Isn't it?

Comment: but browser isn't sending any cookie header

Comment: Browser will send cookies that are sent received via `set-cookie` header. The problem in you design, is that you are trying to send cookie that is retrieved via `httpOnly` flag and is set by server on your browser, through javascript code.

Comment: i removed that line where i am sending the cookie assuming browser  itself will send the cookie but it doesn't. although when i  hit the endpoint directly from chrome  it does send   the cookie with request  but it doesn't not when i'm sending the request from angular

Comment: remove httpOnly flag from your cookie in your `JAVA` code and check again. see if angular can send this cookie via header or not?

Comment: it doesn't, there is one more header in cookie "XSRF-TOKEN" which is not httpOnly but still browser doesn't sends it

Comment: Browser only send and store cookies that are received via response header of `set-cookie`. Also be noted each cookie has a context zone. defined with `path`.

Comment: it came with header `set-cookie` and path is `/` so it should be accessible to every other path right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186253/discussion-between-reza-torkaman-ahmadi-and-nawnit-sen).

Answer (score -2):

I also had this issue, and i just fixed it right now.

I realized that is you pass option `{withCredentials: true}` your browser will automatically send all available cookies along with your request. That way you don't have to add the cookies manually, so it's fluent and i thinks it also safer.

Change your code to this and see and check.

Cookies are available when the path is same as your front end.

```
private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/hi';
 
getMessage() :Observable<Message>{
  return this.http.get<Message>(this.heroesUrl, {withCredentials: true});
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work our for me.

Comment: Really unfortunate, you probably have another underlying problem. @Xonshiz Take a look at the entire cookie object to be sure that it does not contain a flag that is preventing it from being sent.

Comment: Yeah, had checked it and the browser was still showing that "cookie" cannot be set as an header value.

Comment: You have a special case, so voting down this answer is subservient to people who it would have helped.
Even other answer to similar question on here suggest that this is one right way to solve the problem @Xonshiz .

Comment: This works in chrome, but for safari you need a different solution

Comment: @Zyxer22 does the safari solution also work in chrome? 

Please supply the solution so that will not struggle too much.